# edmx ADO.NET generation from tables, but tables not showing

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net, edmx

EDIT: I am using MS SQL server 2008 R2 as well.

Well, on a remote server, I had some tables that show up in the wizard for edmx, but in my local database, I create a database with owner yyyyyy.  As that owner, I ran some fairly simple DDL in the execute query to create a simple table like so

```
USE [Override]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Errors]    Script Date: 05/18/2012 16:08:19 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Errors]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Errors]
GO

USE [Override]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Errors]    Script Date: 05/18/2012 16:08:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Errors](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Errors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

After this I right click on my edmx file and say update from database and give it the new connection AND use the yyyyy user.  Well, there is a Tables checkbox but there is nothing under it.  It is like there is no tables.

For some reason, my remote database is "half-working".  Any tables I create in my remote show up for generation, but none of the existing tables do.

NOTE: I then tried using my "sa" user as I thought he would have supreme power and surely would see the tables but even this didn't help.  Any ideas on why this stuff is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer finally after banging my head against the wall.  You have to create a brand new model instead of use the old one.  Something is hosed up if you change out the connection or something.  The new model goes against your server like so

```
<Server>/<instance>.<Databasename>.dbo
```

which I did not expect since this is my first time doing generation of ADO.NET